# Using multiple layouts in single activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently working on Android project where I need to use multiple layouts in the same activity.

**When the user clicks a button in the main layout, then I need to have another layout(which is completely different) with different content.**

I tried looking up on the Internet and found that Fragments can be used, but as far as I understand Fragments are to be used when one needs only partial changes in the new layout, whereas I need to use a a completely different layout.

Also, I found include, but that is to use the same layout in multiple activities.
So, not what I was looking for.

Does anyone have any idea as to how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not open a new activity with the needed layout when he presses the button?

Comment: use view pager..and on button click just change the layout..remove old layout and add new layout..

Comment: You can do setContentView(R.layout.your_new_layout);

Comment: @Alex, Although in the background, the new layout appeared but the app crashed.

Answer (score 4):

XML  use framelayout. Put your content where I have mentioned <--Your layout-->

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <--Your layout-->

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <--Your layout-->
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Code : Set onclick for button and set visibility.

```
LinearLayout 1ayout1,layout2;
Button button1;

1ayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout1);
1ayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout2);
button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);

1ayout1.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
1ayout2.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            1ayout2.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            1ayout1.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

you can show many fragments in one activity

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so fragments can be used only for partial changes , Hope it works well with dynamic views as well

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
```